# Combine multiple patchworks

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, patchwork

I would like to combine multiple plots created by patchwork in another patchwork, i.e. nested patchwork plots.

Dummy plots

```r
# packages
require(ggplot2)
require(patchwork)

# plots
gg_hist = ggplot(iris) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = Sepal.Length), color = 'white') +
  theme_void()
gg_plot = ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = Sepal.Width))

# patchwork 1
gg1 = gg2 = gg_hist +
  gg_plot +
  plot_layout(heights = c(1,5))
```

I would like to combine `gg1` & `gg2` with the patchwork package to lie next to each other, like in `cowplot::plot_grid(gg1, gg2)`. However they are arranged wrongly. It looks like a bug. Can anyone help?

BUG?

```r
# patchwork 2
Reduce('+', list(gg1, gg2))
gg1 + gg2
```

WORKS:

```r
# cowplot
cowplot::plot_grid(gg1, gg2)
```

---

Package versions: *cowplot_1.1.1   patchwork_1.1.1 ggplot2_3.3.5*

Comment: Seems not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69644490/center-tags-of-nested-plot-using-ggplot-and-patchwork

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `|` :

```r
gg1 | gg2
```

Output is:

[image]

Comment: Oh man, I should have tried that... Thanks!